# Django way to process url .../api/example/merge/{urlparams}/ and process a filtered query in DB

Tags: python, django, django-models

So I'm a newb to python and django, I have GET with the following url `.../api/example/merge/{urlparams}/` in where urlParameters can be like variable in length and number of parameters for example `?derivate=22&engine=52?start_date=2017-03-05?end_date=2017-05-05`

I have read documentation and I have achieve this tiny bit:

```
@list_route(permission_classes=[permissions.AllowAny], url_path='example/(?P<urlparams>[^/]+)$')
def example(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # do something...

    return Response(something)
```

Is this the django way to achieve this, or should I try to do it in some other way?

Comment: What documentation have you read?

Comment: @nik_msome I found online and saw some examples like the one I posted

Comment: I think you should edit your question to be more specific about what you are asking...